# I'm very new to python and one of my images will not draw onto the screen

Tags: python, image, pygame, background, operating-system

I was trying to draw an image onto the screen but I keep getting errors. The error keeps saying "video system not initialized". I am new to python, can anyone help?

```
import pygame
import os
#game window
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
NAME = pygame.display.set_caption("Space War!")
#FPS limit
FPS = (60)

#image i am trying to draw onto screen
SPACE_BACKGROUND = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('space_background.png'))

pygame.init()
#allows pygame to quit
def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                pygame.quit()
        #updates images 
        pygame.display.update()
#calling def main(): function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do:

```
def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    FPS = 60
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                pygame.quit()
        #updates images 
        WIN.blit(SPACE_BACKGROUND, (0, 0)) #you FORGOT this part
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Does it answer ur question?

Comment: It says file not found but it's in my directory. Am I typing the code wrong?

Comment: It works now Aisha. Thank you so much, I put r'C:\Users\bcoff\Downloads\Assets', 'space_background.png' instead of 'Assets', 'space_background'. and it works now. Thanks